# Unable to watch for file changes in this large workspace which has only two cpp files

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am trying to run the first example of zguide (zeromq). The project has two files, client and server, and I am doing this using vscode ssh remote on a RHEL7 machine.

Here is the structure of the folder and how it looks like in VSCode explorer:

```
ZEROMQ[SSH:remote_machine]
|_.vscode
  |_tasks.json
  |_c_cpp_properties.json
|_client.cpp
|_server.cpp
```

Once in a while I receive this warning:

```
Unable to watch for file changes in this large workspace folder. Please follow the instructions link to resolve this issue.
```

The instructions are of course telling me to increase the limit size which I don't think is the issue here with such a small project.

So, any ideas what's happening and how to resolve this?